# How to implement Async with Mongoose method

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

I've got following code now:

```
exports.listByUser = function(req, res) {
    Attack.find({user: req.user._id}, function(err, attacks) {
        if(err) 
            return next(err);
        for(var i in attacks) {
            attacks[i].evaluateFight();
        }
        res.json(attacks);
    });
};
```

the main problem is that `attacks[i].evaluateFight()` is called asynchronously, I want to transform it to make sure that `[i-1]` iteration is done ... and finally call `res.json(attacks)`. I think, it can be done with [async](https://github.com/caolan/async), but I don't know how :( Something like this should work, but how can I call `attacks.method`?

```
async.eachSeries(attacks, function (callback) {
  //something??
  callback();
}, function (err) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  res.json(attacks);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage `async` `whilst` method call to implement the same. However, there is question I have about the callback of `evaluateFight` because if it is executed asynchronously then there has to be some callback associated with it which will notify if the previous call is succeeded.

The example code can be as follows assuming `evaluateFight` returns a callback when completed -

```
exports.listByUser = function(req, res) {
Attack.find({user: req.user._id}, function(err, attacks) {
    if(err) 
        return next(err);
    var attacksLength = attacks.length;
    var count = 0;

    async.whilst(function () { 
          return count < attacksLength; 
       },
       function (callback) {

          attacks[count].evaluateFight(function(err, result){
             count++;
             callback();
          }); // assuming it returns a callback on success

        },
      function (err) {
         // all the iterations have been successfully called 
        // return the response
        res.json(attacks);
     });

};
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick response, but I don't know, how to return callback?
`mongoose.model('Game').findOneAndUpdate({ '_id': game._id }, { '$set': something }, function(err, data) {// return callback HERE});`

Comment: `mongoose.model('Game').findOneAndUpdate({ '_id': game._id }, { '$set': something }, function(err, data) { callback(err, data); // this is the callback thats been passed from async });`

Comment: Also, your `evaluateFight` function should accept a callback as `evaluateFight(callback){ mongoose.model('Game').findOneAndUpdate({ '_id': game._id }, { '$set': something }, function(err, data) { callback(err, data); // this is the callback thats been passed from async }); }`